# Regex pattern for matching C++ method declaration which are not virtual

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex to match method declarations in a C++ header file which are not virtual. I have it working in most cases, however if there is a line feed after virtual and the method declaration is on the next line, my regex will match it, which is not what I want.  Therefore, I need the regex engine to backtrack to the previous line and check for the virtual keyword.  Here's a basic example:

Source file snippet:

```
void Process(char* name, int val); // Should match, this one works
virtual char* GetName(); // Should not match since it is virtual, this one works
virtual
        flag_type SetValue(uint8 resourceIndex, char* name); // Should not match, but this line matches since virtual is on previous line!
```

And here is my regex expression:
`(^\s*\w+\**(?<!virtual)\s+\w+\s*\()(\s*\w+\**\s+\**\w+,?)*\s*\)\s*;`

Comment: There is a logical flaw in your idea: you assume every declaration takes at least one line, but that's not true. If you have `void x(); void y();` on the same line, which is perfectly acceptable in C++, you would only recognize the first function but not the second.

Comment: Thanks for you input.  I realize this will not work in every situation and does not have to, but I was trying to keep this example simple. Ignoring the flaw, how can I make the regex not match when preceded by the virtual keyword on the previous line?

Comment: I found something that works for me, including for the flaw pointed out by Emanuele (although it will also match within commented lines):
`\b(?<!virtual\s+)\w+\**\s+\w+\s*\((\s*\w+\**\s+\**\w+,?)*\s*\)\s*;`

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works for me, including for the flaw pointed out by Emanuele (although it will also match within commented lines): `\b(?<!virtual\s+)\w+\**\s+\w+\s*\((\s*\w+\**\s+\**\w+,?)*\s*\)\s*;`